# Grails: How do I print in the cmd console?

Tags: grails, printing, console, cmd

I wanna print a few values in the console, how do I do this?

Every time I get into a function, I want it to print a line with whatever text, I just wanna know if I'm getting into the function, and for some if-else statements.
Mostly for debugging.

Comment: Perhaps you can give an example of what you're running in the console and what you're trying to print? Your question is kind of vague.

Comment: I have the same question. I am using GGTS and trying to get something to log/print to the console in eclipse. I tried log.info "Hello wolrd" but nothing comes out.  Perhaps I need to change the log level somewhere?  In java I would be using log4j with a console apender, how is this kind of thing possible in grials?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you might want to consider grails built in logging functionality which provides the same functionality as println plus more

http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/guide/single.html#logging

in your app just say

```
log.info "Hello World"
```

to print something everytime you enter an action in a controller you can do something like this

```
class UserController {

    def beforeInterceptor = {
       log.info "Entering Action ${actionUri}"
    }

    def index = {
    }

    def listContributors = {
    }
}
```

this will print out to the log whenever the controller methods are entered because of the [controller interceptor](http://www.grails.org/Controllers+-+Interceptors)

Comment: This will work in Controllers and Services, but it does not get automatically injected in to your own custom classes.  You can either manually inject it, or just use `println`

Comment: I tried log.info("hello") in my controller, but nothing comes out on the console (of eclise with GTS), and there are no log directories or similar.  Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: @JohnLittle, `log.info("hello")` probably didn't display because of the logging level for your application, but `log.println("hello")` and `log.error("hello")` probably will display.

Answer (score 29):

If you mean "print to the console output panel", then you simply need to use `println`:

```
println "Hello, world"
```

Results in printed output:

```
groovy> println "Hello, world" 

Hello, world
```

If that's not what you mean, can you clarify your question to be more specific?

Answer (score 3):

The regular java `System.out.println("Your stuff");` works too.

Comment: For domain classes you will have to implement the toString method otherwise it won't know how to print it.